# Find all primes $p$ such that $p+1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all primes $p$ such that $p+1$ is a perfect square.

All primes except for 2 (3 is not a perfect square, so we can exclude that case) are odd, so we can express them as $2n+1$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$. Let's express the perfect square as $a^2$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$. Since we are interested in a number that is one more than $2n+1$, we know that our perfect square can also be expressed as $2n+1+1=2(n+1)$.

$2n+2=a^2$

$2(n+1)=a^2$

So we know that our perfect square must be even, as it has a factor of 2 in it (in fact $2\cdot2$).

It is my strong intuition that we get a perfect square only if $n=1$, and therefore $p=3$ and $p+1=a^2=2\cdot2=4$, but how should I continue with this proof? It seems to me that whatever factor we have on the LHS we need to have it twice on the RHS (since $a$ must be an integer), but how do I continue from there?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you knew your perfect square would be even already since every prime but 2 is odd.

Comment: You want $p=n^2-1$ then?

Comment: $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$.

Comment: Yes by the conjugate rule it is always factorable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a prime $p$ is of the form of $n^2-1$, then

$$p=(n+1)(n-1)$$

and so $n-1$ must be 1.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that if we have $p+1=k^2$ we can see $p=(k-1)(k+1)$ and hence $3$ is the only such prime.

Answer (score 1):

If our prime $p$ is in form of $n^2-1,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then it could also be written as $p=(n-1)(n+1)$ If $p$ is a prime than it cannot be written as the product of two other primes (or the productof any integer other than $1$ and itself) (states the fundamental theorem of arithmetic) If $n-1=1$ then $n=2$ and the other multiplier $n+1=3=p$. Another possibility is that $n+1=1$ however that doesn't give us a prime for $p$..

So there is only one prime $p$ that makes $p+1$ a perfect square and it is $3$.