# Find all primes $p$ so that $p+1$ is a perfect power.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, factoring

[Inspired by this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464649/find-all-primes-p-such-that-p1-is-a-perfect-square), in a more general setting when can we say that $p+1 = k^n$ ?

If we take a sneak peek to the answers to the linked question.. this would be the same as to try and factor $k^n-1$ which is nice to do if $n=2$. But how can we do that for other $n$? Does there perhaps exist a generalization to the conjugate rule..?

Comment: if $k\neq 2$ it factorizes to $k^n-1=(k-1)(1+k+k^2+...+k^{n-1})$.

Comment: Can we factor the right factor any further in general?

Comment: And what if you look for primes $p$ such that $p-1$ is a perfect power?
$p=2,5,17,37,101,\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k\neq 2$ then $p=k^n -1$ is composite number since it is equal to $(k-1)\cdot\sum_{0\leq j\leq n-1} k^j .$ If $k=2$ then we obtain Mersenne numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$p=k^n-1=(k-1)(k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}+\dots+k+1)$$and this will give a non-trivial factorisation unless $k=2$ (or $n=1$), so you get the Mersenne primes.