# When can we factor $\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} m^l$

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, factoring, perfect-powers

[Inspired by this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464675/find-all-primes-p-so-that-p1-is-a-perfect-power/2464691#2464691) which in the case $k=2$ we would need to factor the second factor too:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} m^l$$
Can we say anything in general for which $n$ or $m$ this will be possible?

---

My own work is limited to concluding that if $n$ is a composite number $n = f_1\cdot f_2$, then:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} m^l = \left(\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{f_1-1} m^l\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum_{l=0}^{f_2-1} m^{l\cdot f_1}\right)$$

For example $n=6 = 3 \cdot 2$ : $$m^5+m^4+m^3+m^2+m^1+1 = (m^2+m^1+1)(m^3+1) = (m+1)(m^4+m^2+1)$$

Comment: When $n + 1$ is prime, these are examples of [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Easy_cases_for_computation). I don't know anything about them, but other people know a lot (of course, this makes $n \ge 4$ even which is a case you seem to have covered). Also, shouldn't these factor into linear and irreducible quadratics for any $n$? Unless I'm misunderstanding, "for which $n$ [...] this will be possible"

Comment: Yes they will factor into quadratics - if we pair up the complex conjugates on the unit circle, but I guess it is not sure that we get integer coefficients? ( which would be required to bust primality of an integer )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$s(m, n)
=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} m^l
$,
then
$s(m, n)
=\dfrac{m^n-1}{m-1}
$.

Also,
from
$x^n-1
=(x-1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j$,
we have the factorizations
$m^{ab}-1
=(m^a-1)\sum_{j=0}^{b-1} m^{ja}
=(m^a-1)s(m^a, b)
$
and
$m^{ab}-1
=(m^b-1)\sum_{j=0}^{a-1} m^{jb}
=(m^b-1)s(m^b, a)
$.

Therefore,
if $n = ab$
then
$s(m, n)
=\dfrac{m^n-1}{m-1}
=\dfrac{m^{ab}-1}{m-1}
=\dfrac{(m^a-1)s(m^a, b)}{m-1}
=s(m, a)s(m^a, b)
$.

We also have
$s(m, n)
=s(m, b)s(m^b, a)
$.